# Does anyone know of any work being done on EEE transformer?

Tags: installation, asus, eeepc

I recently got a (few) nexus 7's to install and enjoy ubuntu on. Which is great and all, but from what I've read online and the issues I have experienced myself the Nexus 7 has way to many serious defects. Such as:

Audio jack not working
Screen lifting
Screen ghosting out (The very first one)
Instant drop in battery life (happened to one of mine)
Internal memory malfunctions (The latest issue I've had, the internal memory went completely bad)

If you need to read other horror stories you can simply check out XDA developers forum, lots of people are having issues.

I'd really like to enjoy ubuntu on a different device, I think the Transformer prime would make way more sense (usability and stability wise). Have there been any hacks/mods to get it running on this device?

Comment: 1.If you have experienced bugs with the Nexus 7 Image it is better to report them as bugs so they can be fixed//2.Officially no, because Canonical is using the Nexus 7 as the "base" device to develop Ubuntu in it's "Mobile" form, there might be chroot  images available for the Transformer but those would be unofficial and wouldn't be off topic here.

Comment: The issues I have had with the Nexus 7 are popular hardware fault, not software related. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, check out the link
http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/ASUS_Eee_Pad_Transformer/How_to_install_Ubuntu
That may not be for the Prime, but should point you in the right direction.